# ansible: Special variables not defined when provisioning to remote host?

Tags: ansible

I can apply an Ansible playbook locally from the remote host itself and all of the [special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) are defined (and most non-empty). However, when I apply it on my local with the remote host as the target, they're all empty. I'd expect that the context should be identical, from the perspective of that remote machine, in both cases.

Specifically, the playbook has a shell task that writes a BASH script. This is most of it:

```
echo "#!/bin/sh" > /usr/local/bin/ml_provision_info
echo             >> /usr/local/bin/ml_provision_info

# Playbook info.
echo "echo 'Playbook Git revision: {{ ml_playbook_revision | default("<not provided>", true) }}'"  >> /usr/local/bin/ml_provision_info
echo "echo 'Playbook version (integer): {{ playbook_version }}'"                                   >> /usr/local/bin/ml_provision_info
echo "echo 'Playbook applied at: $(date)'"                                                         >> /usr/local/bin/ml_provision_info
echo "echo"                                                                                        >> /usr/local/bin/ml_provision_info
echo                                                                                               >> /usr/local/bin/ml_provision_info

# General Ansible context.
echo "echo 'VAR(ansible_dependent_role_names): {{ ansible_dependent_role_names | default([]) | join(',') }}'"  >> /usr/local/bin/ml_provision_info
echo "echo 'VAR(ansible_play_role_names): {{ ansible_play_role_names | default([]) | join(',') }}'"            >> /usr/local/bin/ml_provision_info
echo "echo 'VAR(ansible_role_names): {{ ansible_role_names | default([]) | join(',') }}'"                      >> /usr/local/bin/ml_provision_info
echo "echo 'VAR(ansible_run_tags): {{ ansible_run_tags | default([]) | join(',') }}'"                          >> /usr/local/bin/ml_provision_info
echo "echo 'VAR(ansible_skip_tags): {{ ansible_skip_tags | default([]) | join(',') }}'"                        >> /usr/local/bin/ml_provision_info
echo "echo 'VAR(group_names): {{ group_names | default([]) | join(',') }}'"                                    >> /usr/local/bin/ml_provision_info
echo "echo"                                                                                                    >> /usr/local/bin/ml_provision_info
echo                                                                                                           >> /usr/local/bin/ml_provision_info
```

When we run the playbook from local, the special variables have the expected values:

```
Playbook Git revision: 4967a0f8d249daa36b3a53e0d10d791502030a24
Playbook version (integer): 783
Playbook applied at: Wed Oct 23 01:39:44 UTC 2019

VAR(ansible_dependent_role_names): 
VAR(ansible_play_role_names): resolvconf,jenkins_slave,git,git_tools,kraken_modules,slave_netrc,gcc5.4.1,ntp,docker,guardicore,yaegashi.blockinfile,swarmclient,zabbix_agent,specifics
VAR(ansible_role_names): kraken_modules,git,git_tools,ntp,zabbix_agent,guardicore,specifics,slave_netrc,swarmclient,resolvconf,gcc5.4.1,jenkins_slave,docker,yaegashi.blockinfile
VAR(ansible_run_tags): all
VAR(ansible_skip_tags): 
VAR(group_names): ungrouped
```

However, when we run it from remote, most of the values are *undefined*:

```
Playbook Git revision: 4967a0f8d249daa36b3a53e0d10d791502030a24
Playbook version (integer): 783
Playbook applied at: Wed Oct 23 01:08:16 UTC 2019

VAR(ansible_dependent_role_names): 
VAR(ansible_play_role_names): 
VAR(ansible_role_names): 
VAR(ansible_run_tags): all
VAR(ansible_skip_tags): 
VAR(group_names): ungrouped
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Post [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You're right. I figured it might be a recognizable phenomenon, but I didn't help. Done.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not using [a template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html)?

Comment: Wasn't aware of them. That would be the more optimal strategy (so, thanks for mentioning), but it still doesn't explain the behavior that I'm inquiring about.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how you running ansible on the remote and local?  Is it the same version of ansible, are you running it the same way?

Comment: The GCE provisioning process, which I am not directly involved with, is using 2.4.2.0 . Mine is 2.7.12 . A lot of these are extremely sensible and useful values, so it'd be hard for me to believe that there was no way to get them. However, the special-variables documentation doesn't indicate anything about what versions are supported, the documentation on the website only goes back one version, and the sources for the documentation in GH are untagged. Even the commits to the documentation two years ago may or may not have mentioned it, but it could just be in a different place.

Answer (score 0):

It's not always easy figuring out when something changed in Ansible.
Let's try to figure out when ansible_dependent_role_names was added!

**First option**

This is usually the best way to find out when some code was changed, but it works for finding a var too.
The host vars are generated by lib/ansible/vars/hostvars.py
We can pull in the ansible repo or use GitHub to git blame.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blame/devel/lib/ansible/vars/hostvars.py

Searching for ansible_dependent_role_names yields:
[image]

Looking at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/46483 it states:

> Therefore we introduce 2 new magic variables, and redefine one:
>
> - role_names now includes all role names, including those of dependencies. The most common use case when checking in role_names is
>     to see if the target host is affected by a specific role. The addition
>     of dependencies to this list would not break those use cases, but
>     instead would make them more accurate.
> - play_role_names assumes the role of the former role_names, only listing explicitly listed roles as per the play. Should there be a
>     requirement to see if a role is explicitly configured, this list can
>     be used
> - dependent_role_names lists all roles that are included because they are a dependency of another role. This means they may include roles
>     that are also defined in play_role_names, so a check against
>     play_role_names can verify whether a specific role is only a
>     dependency, or both a dependency and explicitly required.

This commit was added to devel on november 2018, 2.4 was released september 2018.

**Second option**

An easier way to make sure a specific version has a variable is using pip and virtualenv so you can easily switch to older Ansible versions and see with  `ansible all -m setup`.
See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#latest-releases-via-pip

**Third option**

Have a look at the changelogs! Every Ansible major version has their own changelog and the location changed over the years, but let's take [2.8 version](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.8/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.8.rst) In the release notes for 2.8.0:

> - magic variables - added a new ansible_dependent_role_names magic variable to contain the names of roles applied to the host indirectly,
>     via dependencies.
> - magic variables - added a new ansible_play_role_names magic variable to mimic the old functionality of role_names. This variable only lists
>     the names of roles being applied to the host directly, and does not
>     include those added via dependencies
> - magic variables - added a new ansible_role_names magic variable to include the names of roles being applied to the host both directly and
>     indirectly (via dependencies).